# Specify color of classes for mplot3d and show label

Tags: python-3.x, scatter3d

using this code in order to generate a 3D plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d


fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

x= x_pca[:,0]
y= x_pca[:,1]
z = x_pca[:,2]


y_train_new = y_train_orig.argmax(1)

ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c = y_train_new, marker = 'o', alpha=0.6, cmap='inferno')
plt.title("3D Scatterplot: 95% of the variability captured", pad = 15)
ax.set_xlabel('First principal component')
ax.set_ylabel('Second principal component')
ax.set_zlabel('Third principal component')
```

I would like to change the colors of the classes.

This is the output that I get:

[image]

Could the problem lie with my `y_train_new` data?  It is an array of `dtype =int64`?

How do I go about changing the color of for the different classes?  Thanks!

Data:

| feat1 | feat2 | feat3 | feat4 | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -3.8481877 | -0.47685334 | 0.63422906 | 1.0396314 | 1 |
| -2.320888 | 0.65347993 | 1.1519914 | 0.12997247 | 1 |
| 1.5827686 | 1.4119303 | -1.7410104 | -4.6962333 | 1 |
| -0.1337152 | 0.13315737 | -1.6648949 | -1.4205348 | 1 |
| -0.4028037 | 1.332986 | 1.3618442 | 0.3292255 | 1 |
| -0.015517877 | 1.346349 | 1.4083523 | 0.87017965 | 1 |
| -0.2669228 | 0.5478992 | -0.06730786 | -1.5959451 | 1 |
| -0.03318152 | 0.3263167 | -2.116833 | -5.4616213 | 1 |
| 0.4588691 | 0.6723614 | -1.617398 | -4.3511734 | 1 |
| 0.5899199 | 0.66525555 | -1.694493 | -3.9452586 | 1 |
| 1.610061 | 2.4186094 | 1.8807093 | 1.3764497 | 0 |
| 1.7985699 | 2.4387648 | 1.6306056 | 1.1184534 | 0 |
| -9.222036 | -9.9776 | -9.832 | -9.909746 | 0 |
| 0.21364458 | -1.0171559 | -4.9093766 | -6.2154694 | 0 |
| -0.019955145 | -1.1677283 | -4.6549516 | -5.9503417 | 0 |
| 0.44730473 | -0.77167743 | -4.7527356 | -5.971007 | 0 |
| -0.16508447 | -0.005777468 | -1.5020386 | -4.49326 | 0 |
| -0.8654994 | -0.54387957 | -1.300646 | -4.621529 | 0 |
| -1.7471086 | -2.0005553 | -1.7533782 | -2.6065414 | 0 |
| -1.5313624 | -1.6995796 | -1.4394685 | -2.600004 | 0 |

Comment: Hi @Joe - Can you pls share some sample data (few rows) of what is used here? The colors could probably be because black and yellow are the first and last colors of `inferno`

Comment: @Redox, I have added some data as per your request.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @joe- Is this data = x_pca with 0-2 the x,y,z and Label the y_train_new?

Comment: Hello @Redox, yes, columns 0-2 is the x,y,z data and the last column is the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the data provided. As you can see from your data, `Label` is either 0 or 1. As you chose `inferno` as the cmap, the extremes of that colormap are the yellow and black, which is what you are seeing.

The easier way to change the colors is to choose a colormap that has the colors you need, that should help. The set of colormaps is available [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html). You should be able to choose any of the colormaps there. Also, I have modified your code slightly to change the cmap and added an edge so you can see the new plot. If you replace your `ax.scatter(..)` with this....

```
#Using tab10 which is a discrete cmap
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c = y_train_new, marker = 'o', alpha=0.8, s=100, cmap='tab10', edgecolor='k')
```

... you will get this plot

[image]

But, if you need specific colors, then you can create your own colormap and use that instead. The documentation for this is available [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html). Do remember that the number of unique values in your `Label` column should have a color while creating `mycmap` below. As an example, if you replace your `ax.scatter()` with this...

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
mycmap = ListedColormap(["blue", "red"])
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c = y_train_new, marker = 'o', alpha=0.8, s=100, cmap=mycmap, edgecolor='k')
```

...your colormap will change to this.

[image]

Comment: very thorough answer with great examples and explanations.  Thank you!